# Arrow keys in Terminal shortcut don't work

Tags: command-line, bash, gnome-terminal, c++, code-blocks

I am new to Linux and am using Ubuntu 13.04. 
I have a C++ program named "dictionary" (full path: `/home/anmol/Desktop/c++/dictionary`), which I compiled with Code::Blocks IDE (and GCC version 4.7.3).

I have set up a custom keyboard shortcut for it by going into System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts and putting command: `gnome-terminal --disable-factory  -x  /home/anmol/Desktop/c++/dictionary`.

Now the problem I face is that the arrow keys inside the terminal aren't working... For example, whenever I press the left arrow key, I get "^[[D"...
But when I run a terminal normally (by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), the arrow keys work fine.

Now when I googled the problem, I found that this could happen if somehow the default shell had been changed from bash to sh.

So in my c++ program, to see what shell was being used as default, I added the line `system("chsh");` just after the `main()` function and found that the default shell was bash only!
Still I tried by adding the line `system("chsh -s /bin/bash")` but the problem persisted... (when I prefixed `sudo` to the command it threw an error `chsh: PAM:Authentication Failure`)!

Also, in the Code::Blocks Environment Settings Page, I found these 2 settings:

- Shell to run commands in: `/bin/sh -c`
- Terminal to launch console programs: `gnome-terminal --disable-factory -t $TITLE -x`

I changed the "Shell to run commands in": `/bin/bash -c`. But the problem still persisted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First install `rlwrap` tool (in Ubuntu is not installed by default) by running next command in [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```
sudo apt-get install rlwrap
```

Now set up your custom keyboard shortcut using next command:

```
gnome-terminal --disable-factory -x bash -c 'rlwrap -a /home/anmol/Desktop/c++/dictionary'
```

Comment: Thanks a ton!..But is there any way to do this without this tool??..That is, by editing any of the configuration files in Ubuntu..??   ( Just curious to know! )

Comment: @AnmolSinghJaggi You can try a workaround starting from [this post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/66434/delete-key-doesnt-work-on-command-line).